# Unable to Consume Scoped Service via MediatR

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, discord.net, mediatr

I have an ASP.NET Core application running .NET 5 and C# 9. This also runs a Discord bot in the background. My `ConfigureServices()` method in `Startup.cs` looks like this.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    
    var client = new DiscordSocketClient(new DiscordSocketConfig
    {
        AlwaysDownloadUsers = true,
        MessageCacheSize = 10000,
            
        GatewayIntents = GatewayIntents.Guilds | GatewayIntents.GuildMessages |
                         GatewayIntents.GuildMessageReactions | GatewayIntents.GuildPresences,
            
        LogLevel = LogSeverity.Info
    });
        
    var commandService = new CommandService(new CommandServiceConfig
    {
        LogLevel = LogSeverity.Debug,
        DefaultRunMode = RunMode.Sync,
        CaseSensitiveCommands = false,
        IgnoreExtraArgs = false,
    });
    
    services
        .AddMediatR(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly())
        .AddHostedService<StartupService>()
        .AddHostedService<DiscordListener>()
        .AddScoped<ITestService, TestService>()
        .AddSingleton(client)
        .AddSingleton(provider =>
        {
            commandService.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), provider);
            return commandService;
        })
        .AddSingleton(Configuration);
}
```

As you can see, I have added `ITestService` and `TestService` as a scoped service.

```cs
public class TestService : ITestService
{
    public async Task<string> GetString()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
        return "hey";
    }
}

public interface ITestService
{
    Task<string> GetString();
}
```

I then inject this service into my command module.

```cs
public class TestModule : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{
    private readonly ITestService _testService;

    public TestModule(ITestService testService)
    {
        _testService = testService;
    }

    [Command("ping")]
    public async Task Ping()
    {
        var str = await _testService.GetString();
        await ReplyAsync(str);
    }
}
```

However, the application does not respond to the `ping` command. In fact, my handler for receiving messages is not hit at all (I have checked via breakpoint). This is the hosted services that listens for events and publishes the relevant MediatR notifications.

```
public partial class DiscordListener : IHostedService
{
    private readonly DiscordSocketClient _client;
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    public DiscordListener(
        DiscordSocketClient client,
        IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _client = client;
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }
    
    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _client.MessageReceived += MessageReceived;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _client.MessageReceived -= MessageReceived;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    // Creating our own scope here
    private async Task MessageReceived(SocketMessage message)
    {
        using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
        var mediator = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMediator>();
        await mediator.Publish(new MessageReceivedNotification(message));
    }
}
```

And this is the notification handler that handles the notification.

```cs
public class CommandListener : INotificationHandler<MessageReceivedNotification>
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly DiscordSocketClient _client;
    private readonly CommandService _commandService;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public CommandListener(
        IConfiguration configuration,
        DiscordSocketClient client, 
        CommandService commandService, 
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _client = client;
        _commandService = commandService;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }
    
    public async Task Handle(MessageReceivedNotification notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (!(notification.Message is SocketUserMessage message)
            || !(message.Author is IGuildUser user)
            || user.IsBot)
        {
            return;
        }
        
        var argPos = 0;
        var prefix = _configuration["Prefix"];
        
        if (message.HasStringPrefix(prefix, ref argPos))
        {
            var context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, message);
            using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
            await _commandService.ExecuteAsync(context, argPos, scope.ServiceProvider);
        }
    }
}
```

Just to clarify, the breakpoint at `_client.MessageReceoved += ...` is not hit. If I change the `ITestService` and `TestService` implementation to a Singleton, then the handler is hit and the command works as expected. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

[Here](https://github.com/Hamsterland/temp2) is the GitHub repo to the project if you want to see the full code. It is not too large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This a typical problem when mixing Singleton and scoped services. If you end up with situation a singleton is resolving a scoped service it is not allowed.

From docs here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Do not resolve a scoped service from a singleton. It may cause the service to have incorrect state when processing subsequent requests. It's fine to:

Resolve a singleton service from a scoped or transient service.
Resolve a scoped service from another scoped or transient service.
By default, in the development environment, resolving a service from another service with a longer lifetime throws an exception. For more information, see Scope validation.

Also more discussion on https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/03/20/cannot-consume-scoped-service-from-singleton-a-lesson-in-asp-net-core-di-scopes/amp/